# Why $($id:ident),* and $($id:ident,)* behave different in rust macro_rules?

Tags: rust

If we use `$($id:ident,)*` matcher to match tuple with single element, the expansion of macro will be `(A,)` and match tuple with multiple element, the expansion of macro will be (A, B).
If we use `$($id:ident),*` matcher to match them, the expansion will be `(A)` and `(A, B)`.
I want to know why the expansion is different, what is the expand rule behind it? Thanks!

```rust
macro_rules! factory_tuple ({ $($param:ident)* } => {
    impl<Func, Fut, $($param,)*> Handler<($($param,)*)> for Func
    where
        Func: Fn($($param),*) -> Fut + Clone + 'static,
        Fut: Future,
    {
        type Output = Fut::Output;
        type Future = Fut;

        #[inline]
        #[allow(non_snake_case)]
        fn call(&self, ($($param,)*): ($($param,)*)) -> Self::Future {
            (self)($($param,)*)
        }
    }
});

factory_tuple! {}
factory_tuple! { A }
factory_tuple! { A B }
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code that demonstrates what you mean? You seem to be intermixing the *matching* part of the declarative macro and the *expansion* of that matched rule which can be completely different based on what you've written the macro to do.

Comment: I have updated with some code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$($id:ident),*` will expect a comma only between `$id`s and `$($id:ident,)` will expect a comma after every `$id` instead. They are semantically different.

Similarly `$($id),*` will expand to every `$id` separated by commas while `$($id,)*` will expand to every `$id` followed by a comma.

Put it differently, when the comma is put inside the parentheses, then it's part of the group that is repeated, so it is repeated for every item. When it's in between `)` and `*` then it's a separator, so it is only inserted between items.

Comment: If we use $($id:ident,)* matcher to match tuple with single element, the expansion of macro will be (A,) and match tuple with multiple element, the expansion of macro will be (A, B). I check expansion with rust-analyzer.

Comment: No, that pattern doesn't match `(A, B)` you'd have to write it as `(A, B,)`. I believe you're confusing expansions from different attempts.

Comment: You're right, When using `$($id:ident,)` as match rule can only match pattern like (A, B,). Maybe rust-analyzer has processed the raw expansion. Thanks!